# Display a User Control inside of Main Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, visual-studio-2013

Goal:
After clicking on the CRM button, the user control 3 shall be displayed in the mainwindows.

Problem:
I have difficult to create it because I do not know what source code and how to do it.

Information:
- User control 1 is menu with three buttons.
- The main windows will contain totally two user control.
- After you have click the CRM button you should enable to create a new instance of a user control 3 and it should be displayed inside of mainwindows.
- main Windows, User control 1 and 3 has ¨their own project in VS 2013,

[image: Main windows]

[image: user control 1]

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you need to display a usercontrol inside of a window when button is clicked ... if so, define a content control below your usercontrol with buttons, like this

EDIT:
Also add the other 2 projects as a refrence to the mainwindow project.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <UserControl Grid.Row="0"
                     x:Name="userControl1">
            <Button Content="CRM"
                    Click="Button_Click" />
        </UserControl>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                        x:Name="contentHolder" />

    </Grid>
```

And then initialize your usercontrol and set it as the content of the ContentControl in the button click event handler
Make sure to import the namespace of the referenced usercontrols project.

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            contentHolder.Content = new UserControl3();
        }
```

Comment: If the problem is that each usercontrol has it's own project then add a reference to other 2 projects in the main window project ...

Comment: After you have read the new info, does the code above still usable in this context?

Comment: Yes, just add the namespace of the usercontrol3 to the mainwindow codebehind.

Comment: The source code that you have written, should it be paste in the main windows?

Comment: No, this was an example ... you can adapt it to your code easily